# How to strikethrough content in tinymce editor?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, tinymce

I am using [angular2-tinymce](https://github.com/Ledzz/angular2-tinymce) library to work with tinymce editor in my Ionic/Angular project. Now i want to strike through the content of the editor based on one some logic. My attempts are below:

## Attempt-1:

I tried to assign a `strikethrough` css class to the `app-tinymce`.

```
// .html file
<app-tinymce class="note-input-textarea" [(ngModel)]='noteText'
          [ngClass]="{
                       strikethrough: isDeleted
                     }"
          [disabled]="canUpdateNoteDetail">
    </app-tinymce>

// .scss file
.strikethrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

But it didn't work.

## Attempt-2:

```
// .ts file
 export class UpdateProgressNotePage {
  @ViewChild(TinymceComponent) private tinyMce: TinymceComponent;
  isDeleted: boolean = true;
  noteText: string = "Sample Note";
   constructor(){
     this.initialize();
   }
   
   initialize() {
     if(isDeleted) {
       this.tinyMce.editor.execCommand('Strikethrough', false);
       this.tinyMce.editor.execCommand('Strikethrough', false, this.noteText); // Tried with this also but didn't work
     } 
   }

 }
```

But it didn't work for me. I found in this [link](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/editor-command-identifiers/) that `Strikethrough` command can be applied to tinyMce editor.

Comment: To exec the command you need to have some text selected.

Comment: can you please elaborate? suppose i have the content of the editor as `noteText`. How to strike through the content? I have tried with `this.tinyMce.editor.execCommand('Strikethrough', false, this.noteText);` .. But it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just triggering the Strikethrough command does not do anything if there is no text selected in the editor. If you want to strike all the content of tinymce, do something like that

```
this.tinyMce.editor.execCommand('SelectAll');
this.tinyMce.editor.execCommand('Strikethrough', false);
```

Otherwise, you can manually specify the selection if you don't want all the text.

**Edit**: you might need to move that code to ngAfterViewInit, or wrap it in a setTimeout, or figure out a way to trigger it only once tinyMce rendering is complete

Regarding your attempt #1, I don't think setting the strikethrough class will work if the content of tinymce is rendered in an iframe. But if it's rendered inline (https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/inline/), you'll need to use the ::ng-deep combinator

```
//component.css
::ng-deep app-tinymce .strikethough
{
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: Do you see the text being selected? And I edited my post fo your attempt #1

Comment: content of tinymce is being rendered in an iframe. You can see the image https://ibb.co/dJo8JH. What should i do in that case?

Comment: Check why the other solution does not work? Does the selectAll work?

Comment: This `this.tinyMce.editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, data.savedNote); ` command is working. But selectAll is not working..

Comment: I'm not sure it's hard to tell just like that... maybe it's a timing issue? The selectAll might be triggered before content is rendered? Try wrapping the selectAll and strikethrough commands in a setTimeout, just to see

Comment: I have debugged the code. I am using ngModel to set the noteText in the app-tinymce. After that line, the selectAll command is executing. But at this time there was no text populated in the editor. Why?

Comment: Databinding probably happens after oninit. try moving your code to ngAfterViewInit, or use a setTimeout. I updated the answer

Comment: in `ngAfterViewInit`, i am not getting the text populated in the tinyMce editor. And that's why it is creating problem.. Any suggestion?

Comment: My iframe is not loading in ngAfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

If the appropriate content already has a `strikethrough` class associated with it you can just use the `content_css` TinyMCE configuration setting to pass whatever CSS you need to the editor.

Assuming you are not using TinyMCE's inline editing setup, the editor's content area is an iFrame so passing CSS to the main page will have no impact on the HTML inside the iFrame.  The `content_css` TinyMCE configuration setting applies the referenced CSS to the iFrame and would then style the content as needed.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/#content_css